# ios:How to an animation while i send request to my sever to control the refresh image rotate 360°

Tags: ios, animation, rotation

so as the title, when the net request callback, stop the animation in this way:if the request immediately back, it will stop after 360 degrees rotated to recovery before the animation working. if it's the time is so lang, it will stop after 360 * (integer number) degrees.
What can i do to control it perfect?
My programming language is Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGFloat angle = 2 * M_PI;
refreshAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
refreshAnimation.delegate = self;
refreshAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
refreshAnimation.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
refreshAnimation.additive = YES;
refreshAnimation.byValue = @(angle);
refreshAnimation.duration = 0.9 ;
refreshAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animationStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
[btn.layer addAnimation:refreshAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Then use the time to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Last night i solved this,but it's not perfect
First,creat an animation:

```
- (void)initAnimation{
[CATransaction begin];
CGFloat angle = 1000000 * 360 * M_PI/180.0;
refreshAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
refreshAnimation.byValue = @(angle);
refreshAnimation.duration = 1.0 * 1000000;
refreshAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
refreshAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

[CATransaction commit];
```

}

Second,before send request, add the animation to the imageView:

```
    - (void)sendRequst{
[refreshImageView.layer addAnimation:refreshAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[self sendRequstToSever];
```

}

Finally,when the server feedback,remove the animation and set the imagView to the original position:

```
- (void)changeAnimationStatus{
[refreshImageView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.30 animations:^{
    refreshImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.view.transform, 0.0);
}];}
```